# SQL query that gives a point ranking to results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm implementing a basic search on a table that has `title`, `content`, and `tag` columns simply by using a `LIKE` with on the column values. I want all rows that matched based on the `title` to be assigned 3 points, rows that matched based on `tag` to get 2 points, and matches based on `content` to get 1 point.

Is it possible to get this all into a query rather than needing to use 3 queries? I've currently got:

```
SELECT * FROM node WHERE title LIKE '%keywords%'
```

I'm using SQLite in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Edit your question and show the query that you have.

Comment: I'd be tempted to say `case`, but it would depend on the size of the dataset

Comment: Make sure you have indices on all three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case`:

```
select (case when <title condition> then 3
             when <content condition> then 2
             when <tag condition> then 1
        end) as points, t.*
from t
where <title condition> or <content condition> or <tag condition>;
```

I don't know what the conditions are.  You can fill that in.

If, perchance, you want the points to add up (to a total of up to 6 for a row), the logic is similar:

```
select ((case when <title condition> then 3 else 0 end) +
        (case when <content condition> then 2 else 0 end) +
        (case when <tag condition> then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as points, t.*
from t
where <title condition> or <content condition> or <tag condition>;
```

Comment: @JohnHC hinted at a concern based on the size of the dataset. Might there reach a point at which 3 queries would end up being more performant? I'll obviously do my own testing :)

Comment: @maxedison . . . Given your conditions, one query should be the fastest method (saves two scans of the table plus the `or`s are short-circuited).  However, if performance is an issue, then you should consider a full-text index.